# What does ls and -lh/usr mean in NodeJs?

Tags: node.js, child-process

When using the child-process module in NodeJs, what does the `ls` and `-lh/usr` stand for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're referring to the [example for `spawn()`](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options):

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    ls    = spawn('ls', ['-lh', '/usr']);

// ...
```

`ls` is, from left to right:

- A variable referring to the `ChildProcess` instance created and returned by `spawn()`.
- The name of a common unix/linux command for [listing the contents of a directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ls).

The snippet is equivalent to executing the following command in a shell/terminal, where spaces separate the command and arguments:

```
ls -lh /usr
```

Which will try to list the contents of the `/usr` directory, specifying `-lh` as 2 combined options to output in "*long listing format*" (`-l`) with "*human readable sizes*" (`-h`).

It assumes the system running the code has a compatible `ls` command or executable.